# Responsive design - Resizing my desktop browser to iPhone resolution is not the same

Tags: iphone, mobile, web, responsive-design

I am testing the responsiveness of my site on my computer. I'm using a chrome plugin to adjust the browser dimensions to the iPhone's (and other mobile devices), but it is not displayed the same as if I viewed it on my phone. Why is this? How can I test this properly?

This is an example of a media query I'm using (not the iPhone's):

```
@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
.disp{ width:695px; min-height:322px; margin:376px auto 0 auto;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use iPhone simulator on mac, or use some online testing service like [Browser Stack](http://browserstack.com), which sadly costs money. 
You can also try changing your Device under "Emulation" on chrome's developer tools.

Comment: What about other mobile devices? There has to be an easy way to test all of them, on your own browser without launching a sim for each.

Do you know what services like browser stack do differently that isn't possibly by simply changing the resolution in the browser?

Comment: They use virtual machines and boot you into them as if you are on the device itself, I believe. The closest you can get without a physical device or paying is doing what you are doing. But I use a slightly cleaner and nicer looking method that uses a bookmarklet, it lets you easily change sizes of browser window to test responsive design. http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you! This is adjusting to new devices within my own browser, I wonder what they're doing differently. Maybe it's viewport size and not screen resolution?